# GIDSignInButton is blank

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-signin

I'm trying to add google login to my iOs app as described here:
[Integrating Google Sign-In into your iOS app](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in)

However, when I add the button to storyboard, it is blank. I can see that some shadow applied and it is clickable, but it have no text on it (The white button at the right side):

[image]

To create Google login button I just added UIView and set its class to GIDSignInButton... Could you please tell what am I still missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turned out that Pods were not initiated properly and Targets->Project->Build Phases->Copy Pods Resources was missing. Deleting Pods directory didn't help.

The solution was:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

Answer (score 2):

That's old enough question, I know. But I've met the issue. In case if someone is too, my `GIDSignInButton` View was blank because under Custom Class the `Module` was set to "Inherit Module From Target", it shouldn't and `Module` should be `None`.

Other options didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Targets -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources` and add the `GoogleSignIn.bundle`.

This should solve the issue.